# VsCode - Source control shows multiple copies of file changes

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, whenever there's a change in a file, VsCode creates multiple copies for each change which are shown in the source control, I don't know why has that started to happen:
[image]

Comment: Is it just a change or is it a file operation (rename/delete)?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Just a change

Comment: Can you add a larger screenshot please?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Ahh my bad, these are all .history files, I had the history extension installed, disabling it resolves it.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, feel free to add an answer yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

A vsCode extension called **Local History** for maintaining local history of files, when enabled, creates a copy of the old contents kept in the local history, every time you modify a file.

Disabling the extension was the solution here! :)